# add loop from keywords to regular expressions

Tags: python-3.x, regex, pandas

I am trying to organize a loop to avoid a large number of keywords to be inserted in a regular expression. My aim is to extract a 'street' or 'avenue' or 'road' name preceeding these keywords. So far I reached this stage which does not work as a loop. Is it possible to do something like this?

```
keywords = ['street','avenue','road']
for i in keywords:
    df['street'] = df['address'].str.extract('(\d[A-z -]+ i')
```

My input dataset consists of several columns. One of them is address. Eg.: UK, Manchester, Oxford road, 57 . I just need to extract part of this data to a separate column.

My expected output:

Oxford road

Comment: Where should `Lake street, Oxford road` come from? What is the input string?

Comment: Did you mean to write `'(\d[A-z -]+) ' + i`?

Comment: Why do you have `\d` at the beginning of the regexp?

Comment: `A-z` is not valid, that also matches characters that are between the uppercase and lowercase letters in ASCII code. Use `A-Za-z`, or just one of them and `re.IGNORECASE`.

Answer (score 0):

Make a single regexp that matches all the keywords, and concatenate that to the part that matches the street name.

```
import re

keywords = ['street','avenue','road']
keywords_re = '|'.join(map(re.escape, keywords))
df['street'] = df['address'].str.extract(rf'([-a-z ]+ (?:{keywords_re}))', flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

You also shouldn't have `\d` at the beginning of the regexp, since there's no digit at the beginning of your street names.

Comment: thank you very much for your help. There are digits for some of my street names in the dataset. It came from a different style of naming streets. I just changed it for simplicity.

Comment: Do you mean like `42nd Street`? You could have `\d*` at the beginning to match that.

Comment: Yes, something like this. I see, thank you. I just was afraid to change the focus of my question. Next time I will try to be more accurate and careful to details asking something.